# How do I iterate over elements in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I find out each element present in a column of a pandas dataframe?
I would like to do something like this:

```
for item in column:
    print("usercode = " + item)

# OUTPUT:
# usercode = key00
# usercode = key01
# usercode = key02
```

The dataframe is like this:

```
     USERCODES    NAMES
0    key00        ab00
1    key01        cd01
2    key02        ef02
```

Comment: `for i, row in df.iterrows(): print(row['USERCODES'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And for each value in column use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
def f(item):
    print("usercode = " + item)

df['NAMES'].apply(f)
usercode = ab00
usercode = cd01
usercode = ef02
```

One line:

```
df['NAMES'].apply(lambda item: print("usercode = " + item))

usercode = ab00
usercode = cd01
usercode = ef02
```

Simpliest:

```
for item in df['NAMES']:
    print("usercode = " + item)

usercode = ab00
usercode = cd01
usercode = ef02
```

Comment: Is df1 an array?

Comment: No, it is DataFrame.

Comment: I think earlier answer was right  `df['USERCODES'].radd('usercode = ')` or `'usercode = ' + df['USERCODES']`

Comment: I would like to have an output like this: "usercode = key00", "usercode = key01", "usercode = key02". How can I do?

Comment: And output is only print? Or list, dict?

Comment: @jezrael Only print